# Using shared_ptr to access addresses in vector to creat a linked list

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Here, I am trying to make an array of `nodes`, which will also be linked as a linked list. I am purposely making the vector and linked list together, so as to make them contiguous, and when I pop from the vector, I can still refer to the memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<node> next;
};

int main(){
    vector<node> myArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        myArray.push_back(node());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        myArray[i].data = i;
        myArray[i].next.reset(&myArray[i+1]);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<node> nodeList(make_shared<node>());
    auto here = nodeList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        here->next.reset(&myArray[i]); // the error occurs in this line
        here = here->next;
    }

    here = nodeList;
    here = here->next;
    while (here != nullptr) {
        cout << here->data << " with address of : " << &(*here) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error stating `error for object 0x7fb8cbc033d0: pointer being freed was not allocated`. Why is this happening? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: 1. I do not see `new` in your code. 2. Read about smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1) The pointer you assigned to myArray[i].next is not allocated by anyone, so it will barf when shared_ptr try to delete it.

2) myArray[i].next.reset(&myArray[i+1]); is dangerous, because the vector could reallocate the memory it uses, and this pointer will be invalid.

3) A linked list node doesn't have to store a pointer, you could store a next_index filed and do myArray[i].next_index = i + 1 or something like that.

4) You could also store shared_ptr in the vector if that's what you want.